# how to read Int arraylist in parcelable in android

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I am making a data class for Parcelable.
but unable to find out a solution that, how to read integer ArrayList in Parcelable class in kotlin.
I know about String, but I face a problem in the Int type ArrayList.

```
var priceDetail: ArrayList<Int?>?,
```

for more detail see this,

```
    data class PostCardsListData(
        var arrDescriptionsTags: ArrayList<String?>?,
        var priceDetail: ArrayList<Int?>?,
..........

: Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.createStringArrayList(), // i know about string
        //but how to read this Integer arraylist
```

**this is my full data class code**

```
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
data class PostCardsListData(
    var arrDescriptionsTags: ArrayList<String?>?,
    var priceDetail: ArrayList<Int?>?,

) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.createStringArrayList(),
        parcel.//describe me what i will write here

    )

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeStringList(arrDescriptionsTags)
        parcel.write//describe me what i will write here
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<PostCardsListData> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): PostCardsListData {
            return PostCardsListData(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<PostCardsListData?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try using `parcel.readSerializable()`

Comment: its not working

Type mismatch.
Required:
kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Int?>? /* = java.util.ArrayList<Int?>? */

Found:
Serializable?

Comment: yea because you should type cast it, `parcel.readSerializable() as required_type`

Comment: ok, so please take me direct answer how to read this Int arraylist,
like i write for string arraylist.
        parcel.createStringArrayList(),

Comment: `parcel.readSerializable() as ArrayList<Int?>?`,check if this solves the issue

Comment: i also try this.but its takes issue
Unchecked cast: Serializable? to kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Int?>? /* = java.util.ArrayList<Int?>? */

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227247/discussion-between-rcs-and-shirsh-shukla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to create a parcelable class.

Firstly, Add add plugin to the gradle

```
plugins {
    .
    .
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

Then, create a class and use annotations to parcelize the data

```
@Parcelize
class PostCardsListData(

    @SerializedName("arrDescriptionsTags")
    var arrDescriptionsTags: ArrayList<String>? = null,

    @SerializedName("priceDetail")
    var priceDetail: ArrayList<Int?>? = null

) : Parcelable
```

To read/write data you just need to create an object of this class and use the dot operator to access the list.

In the activity/fragment/viewModel class

```
private var listData = PostCardsListData()

//read data

private var priceList : ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
if(listData.priceDetail != null){
    priceList.addAll(listData.priceDetail)
}
```

Comment: Ok,but main problem is how to read integer array list.see my question

Comment: okay, I have updated the answer please have a look.

Comment: please take answer in kotlin, also take direct suggestion for read arraylist,
like i read string arraylist
        parcel.createStringArrayList(), // i know about string

Answer (score 0):

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
   out.writeList(priceDetail);
}

private PostCardsListData(Parcel in) {
   priceDetail = new ArrayList<>();
   in.readList(priceDetail, Integer.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

or for custom classes use

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
   out.writeTypedList(listCustomClass);
}

private PostCardsListData(Parcel in) {
   listCustomClass = in.createTypedArrayList(CustomClass.CREATOR);
}
```

Comment: please take answer in kotlin, also take direct suggestion for read arraylist,
like i read string arraylist
        parcel.createStringArrayList(), // i know about string